Why is the text cycle I created in FramerMotion and React overlapping at seemingly random times?
I am trying to create an infinite text cycle in React using FramerMotion, showing one word at a time, and cycling to the next word every three seconds. The code below works like a charm a lot of the time, but if I leave the page open, change some windows, do some other stuff, etc, and then come back, often multiple words from the words array are displayed on the page at the same time, and are overlapping one another. I have been wrestling with this for too long now, and can't seem to figure out what makes this happen, or even how to trigger it happening. Anyone have any ideas??
const words = ["Developer", "Nerd", "Humanist", "Mathlete", "Creative", "Coder", "Filmmaker", "Artist", "Listener"]

const TextCycle: React.FC = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex(prevIndex => (prevIndex + 1) % words.length);
    }, 3000)

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden', height: '1em' }}>
        <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
          <motion.div
            style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
            key={index}
            initial={{ y: '-80%', opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ y: '0%', opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ y: '80%', opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.37 }}
          >
            <StyledTextCycle>
              {words[index]}
            </StyledTextCycle>
          </motion.div>
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TextCycle

I tried setting the interval back to zero when there was a visibility change (like if someone tabbed away from the page), and I add in the initial={false}. I also sped up the animation to watch it over and over and seemed like there was no rhyme or reason as to when it happens.

I got the same issue actually

What seems to have worked for me was to change the mode option on the <AnimatePresence/> component from framer-motion
I had the same issue when using mode='wait' or mode='sync' but using mode='popLayout' fixes this weird timing issue.
In your example above that would be something like below :
<AnimatePresence mode="popLayout">
   <motion.div
            key={index}
            initial={{ y: "-80%", opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ y: "0%", opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ y: "80%", opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.37 }}>
            {words[index]}
   </motion.div>
</AnimatePresence>

Here is the link to a codesanbox
Hope it helps

this is the animation i used on my website actually https://x-squad.com
